# LINQ to SQL DataContext connection error reporting

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Okay, so I have this LINQ to SQL situation. I have a DataContext object which links to an SQL database and I can get tables and... all of that business. This is all inside a WCF service inside IIS.

Now I connect the DataContext object when I declare it, which is at the top of the class, as follows:

```
DataContext dc = new DataContext([ConnectionString]);
```

Then, later, I have methods to do things like inserting a Client (that is a type of entity), and that looks something like this:

```
public void InsertClient(Client client)
{
   if(client.ClientID > 0)
      return;

   dc.Clients.InsertOnSubmit(client);

   dc.SubmitChanges();
}
```

The problem is basically... is there some way to test that connection? What if someone pulled a plug or something before SubmitChanges? It's not like it returns anything, so it couldn't tell me there was a particular error.

How would people recommend I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DataContext.SubmitChanges` will throw if there is an error.

Comment: Probably something like `A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server`

Answer (score 1):

```
public bool InsertClient(Client client)
{
   if(client.ClientID > 0)
      return;

   dc.Clients.InsertOnSubmit(client);

   try
   {
      dc.SubmitChanges();
      return true;
   }
   catch
   {
        return false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the datacontext has the public DataContext.Connection Property so if you want you can do anything you want with it...

But I do not think that is particually usefull since Submitchanges anyway will throw like is written in the other answer.